# Algumas bibliotecas não aparecem na lista de pesquisa de dependências

Tags: android-studio

Quando vamos no menu de configuração Project Structure, na configuração do app, e em Dependencies, temos como adicionar algumas bibliotecas numa lista ou pesquisa. Mas não é qualquer biblioteca que aparece. Por exemplo quando eu pesquiso por volley, ele não aparece nesta lista.

Alguém sabe como colocar mais itens nesta lista? As vezes esqueço como está o link da biblioteca para colocar no gradle, e queria um método mais fácil para toda vez que iniciar um novo projeto, poder adicionar mais fácil por esse menu.

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso? Desculpe se eu não soube explicar direito.

Abaixo deixo uma imagem para mostrar sobre a tela de que estou falando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode adicionar novos repositórios no `gradle`: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven

Comment: Obrigado por responder @ValdeirPsr, mas se eu colocar no gradle ele vai aparecer em qualquer novo projeto que eu criar? Eu não entendo muito de inglês, e a tradução não fica tão clara para mim.  Tenho dúvidas de como fazer isso no android studio, se vou por um menu específico, se coloco no gradle do meu projeto e automaticamente servirá pra todos, e como eu consigo os links dos repositórios? Se não for muito incomodo, poderia me dar uma resposta mais detalhada? Desculpe a minha ignorância no assunto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por aquilo que me é dado a perceber a pesquisa só funciona para bibliotecas cujo identificador começa com `com.android` ou `com.google.android`.

Assim sendo terá de conhecer o identificador completo da biblioteca para a poder adicionar.
Repare que mesmo que coloque o identificador completo ele não aparece no resultado da pesquisa, no entanto ela será adicionada ao clicar em <kbd>OK</kbd>.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poxa, bem que o android studio poderia facilitar, deixando adicionar outros repositores para pesquisar nesta listagem. Espero que eles melhorem isto nas próximas versões.